# How to make arguments to mutually exculsive group?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, command-line-interface, argparse

I have a mutually exclusive group where the user can choose from `--execute, --delete, --create`. How can I make arguments only available for specific groups? For example `--execute {filename}`, `--create -fn {filename} -p {path}` and `--delete {filename}`. How can I group up the optional arguments so they only can be used in a specific group?

Comment: Take a look at [sub parsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Comment: Sure, but how would I implement it with `add_mutually_exclusive_group`, there's not an example? @Wombatz

Comment: The commands from sub parsers are already mutually exclusive. You don't need that function.

Comment: Okay! But it's not then possible to use `-e`? Writing `execute` takes time and is a bit annoying.... @Wombatz

Comment: Mutually exclusive groups are flat - xor.  They don't implement any sort of any/all subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three "options" `--execute`, `--delete` and `--create` look like they should be sub-commands and not **optional** flags.

For this, use the `ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()`

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser


parser = ArgumentParser()
sub = parser.add_subparsers()

execute = sub.add_parser('execute')
execute.add_argument('filename')

create = sub.add_parser('create')
create.add_argument('-fn')
create.add_argument('-p')
```

The usage is then

- `program execute {filename}`
- `program create -fn {filename} -p {path}`

You can even create an alias for the sub parsers:

```
sub.add_parser('execute', aliases=['e'])
```

This also allows you to call the program like this:

- `program e {filename}`

**Note**:

It is not possible to use `--execute` or `-e` as the command for a sub parser, because when typing `program --execute {filename}` the `--execute` part is interpreted as a flag for the root parser and not as a sub command.